# Destroy asynchronous request on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using AngularJS and I have a state `dashboard` and the controller makes a request for an array of items.

```
var promise = itemsRestService.fetchAllitems();

promise.then(
    function(response){
        itemService.sortItems(response);
        $scope.dashboardData = response;
        $state.go('dashboard.content', {items: response}, {reload: false});
        vm.dashboardLoaded = true;

    }
)
```

As you can see once the promise has been returned, it directs the user to the child state `dashboard.content`.

The promise can take few seconds to resolve and if I was to click on a navigation item to change state mid request, I would be directed to the new state, but when the promise resolves, it re-directs me back to the `dashboard` state (which is expected).

**Question**

How do I cancel the promise on state `$destroy`?

Comment: A promise can't be cancelled (unless you use a third party libary like BluebirdJS) but could you either show a loader to prevent the user clicking a navigation item whilst loading or check the current view before performing your `$state.go`?

Comment: It's a solution but ignoring the state change, the promise will still be resolving when on another state. I'll have to check the current state instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that
>   should abort the request when resolved.

controller:

```
vm.canceler = $q.defer();
...
const config = {timeout: canceler.promise};
$http.get(`url`, config);
...

vm.$onDestroy = () => {
  vm.canceler.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello guess code only answer is much better than upvoted comment with wrong statement. Also code here is very much self-explaining, but nvm added some text.

Comment: Hi @Petr. I agree that the solution should be stated as an answer, and not in the comments...Despite this, your question was [flagged as _Low Quality_](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24646589), and I'm only following the [good practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300694/what-to-do-with-code-only-answers-in-low-quality-posts-queue) for reviewing it. Thanks for adding some context, this prevents someone to 
misinterpret the review and mark your question for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

One can check the value of `$scope.$$destroyed`:

```
var promise = itemsRestService.fetchAllitems();

promise
  .then(function(response) {
    if ($scope.$$destroyed) throw "Scope destroyed";
    //ELSE
    return response;
}).then(function(response){
        itemService.sortItems(response);
        $scope.dashboardData = response;
        $state.go('dashboard.content', {items: response}, {reload: false});
        vm.dashboardLoaded = true;    
})
```

If the `$scope` has been destroyed, the promise is rejected and avoids subsequent `.then` blocks in the chain.